# Get the name of the symbol by its code point

Tags: rust

How do you do that in rust? For example, the code point "129768 (dec)" is "Shaking Face", how do I do that in the program?

Comment: A quick Google search reveals https://docs.rs/unicode_names2/latest/unicode_names2/.

Answer (score 0):

Installation:
cargo add unicode_names2

Using:

```
fn main() {
    println!("☃ is called {:?}", unicode_names2::name('☃')); // SNOWMAN
    println!("{:?} is happy", unicode_names2::character("white smiling face")); 
}
```